# Java Thread Safety - Multiple access to method, unless another method is in use

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm looking for the best approach to my problem:

I have a bayesian model class that you can call `classify` on. I want as many threads to access this as possible. However, I have another method that would alter the internal structure of the object `removeCategory`.

Is it possible for me to prevent threads from accessing `classify` only while `removeCategory` is being accessed?

I think I might achieve this with a semaphore, where `classify` acquires 1 permit per thread, while `removeCategory` acquires max permits. That way it'll block til all threads are done with `classify`, and another thread cannot start a `classify` call until the permits have been released.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you're describing is in essence a [readwritelock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html). treat your `classify()` method as a reader and your `removeCategory()` method as a writer and you'll get your desired behavior - the class will allow an unlimited amount of readers in but a writer will block all others (including other writers)

there's an example for using this class [here](http://ilkinbalkanay.blogspot.co.il/2008/01/readwritelock-example-in-java.html) (and in plenty of other places)